# Installing LuaSql-MySql Driver on WIndows

Tags: mysql, windows, lua, installation

I have a specialized application that uses LUA for a scripting engine, I need to write a script to perform database work - connecting to MySql. I have been having an issue with the Installer for the LuaSQL-luamysql driver. I have tried version 2.4 of LuaRocks and also version 3.04 (after installing 2.4 and then using 3.04 I seem to be further; now I am getting failed finding Lua Library you may need to configure lua_libdir .

So where do I do this? BTW I do not have a complete install of LUA - I have a specialized app that utilizes lua scripting and has the LUA51.dll in its root directory and also mysql.dll (I do have a full version of MySQL v8.0 loaded.)

I am running Win 7x64.
Used this command:
luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_DIR="C:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"

Comment: Can you clarify, the error your getting is when you attempt to `require('luasql.mysql')` correct? or is it when you are trying to building off the rockspec?

Comment: @Nifim the error I am getting is when I am trying to run luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_DIR="C:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"